# Python Script to Post to Facebook Album Based on Album Name

Tags: python, image, post, facebook-group

I've created a Python script which posts a photo to an album of a group page in Facebook.  This works fine when I know the album ID where I'd like the image to go; however, I want to be able to to have this script post to an album based on the album name, rather than the ID (or a method to get the album ID, based on the name of the album).  Is something like this do-able?

Comment: Just wanted to clarify - I will know the page ID of the group page where the albums reside, and the names of the albums - I want to be able to find the album id's based on this information.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is struggling with this, here is how I accomplished it:

```
    groupDict=graph.get_object (cat='single', id=groupID, fields=['albums']) 
    albumDict = groupDict['albums']['data']

    for j in albumDict:
        if FBalbumName == j['name']:
            albumID = j['id']
            graph.put_photo(image=imagePath, message=message, album_path=albumID+"/photos")
```